# Segmentation Fault occurring with Quicksort

Tags: c++, c, sorting, segmentation-fault

```
int main() {
    int yearsToLoop;
    cin >> yearsToLoop;
    annual_stats* ptr = new annual_stats [yearsToLoop];
    for (int i = 0; i < yearsToLoop; i++)
    {
        int annualYear;
        cin >> annualYear;
        ptr[i].year = annualYear;
        for (int j = 0; j < NO_TEAMS; j++)
        {
            string team_name;
            getline(cin, team_name, '\t');
            strcpy(ptr[i].teams[j].team_name, team_name.c_str());

            int games;
            cin >> games;
            ptr[i].teams[j].games = games;

            float pts_per_game;
            cin >> pts_per_game;
            ptr[i].teams[j].pts_per_game = pts_per_game;

            int total_points;
            cin >> total_points;
            ptr[i].teams[j].total_points = total_points;

            int scrimmage_plays;
            cin >> scrimmage_plays;
            ptr[i].teams[j].scrimmage_plays = scrimmage_plays;

            float yds_per_game;
            cin >> yds_per_game;
            ptr[i].teams[j].yds_per_game = yds_per_game;

            float yds_per_play;
            cin >> yds_per_play;
            ptr[i].teams[j].yds_per_play = yds_per_play;

            float first_per_game;
            cin >> first_per_game;
            ptr[i].teams[j].first_per_game = first_per_game;

            int third_md;
            cin >> third_md;
            ptr[i].teams[j].third_md = third_md;

            int third_att;
            cin >> third_att;
            ptr[i].teams[j].third_att = third_att;

            int third_pct;
            cin >> third_pct;
            ptr[i].teams[j].third_pct = third_pct;

            int fourth_md;
            cin >> fourth_md;
            ptr[i].teams[j].fourth_md = fourth_md;

            int fourth_att;
            cin >> fourth_att;
            ptr[i].teams[j].fourth_att = fourth_att;

            int fourth_pct;
            cin >> fourth_pct;
            ptr[i].teams[j].fourth_pct = fourth_pct;

            int penalties;
            cin >> penalties;
            ptr[i].teams[j].penalties = penalties;

            int pen_yds;
            cin >> pen_yds;
            ptr[i].teams[j].pen_yds = pen_yds;

            string top_per_game;
            cin >> top_per_game;
            strcpy(ptr[i].teams[j].top_per_game, top_per_game.c_str());

            int fum;
            cin >> fum;
            ptr[i].teams[j].fum = fum;

            int lost;
            cin >> lost;
            ptr[i].teams[j].lost = lost;

            int to;
            cin >> to;
            ptr[i].teams[j].to = to;
        }
    }
    int numberOfC;
    cin >> numberOfC;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfC; i++)
    {
        string command;
        cin >> command;

        if(command == "qsort") {
            string command2;
            cin >> command2;
            int num = atoi(command2.c_str());
            if (num >= 2010)
            {
                string year;
                year = command2;
                string field;
                cin >> field;
                string order;
                cin >> order;
                qSortYearFieldOrder(year, field, order, ptr, yearsToLoop);
            }
        }
```

So right here in (part of) the main I get all the inputs and then call a function using some of the inputs. I am currently getting errors with the qSortYearFieldOrder(year, field, order, ptr, yearsToLoop).

```
void qSortYearFieldOrder(string year, string field, string order, annual_stats* ptr, int amountYears) {
    int yearIndex = 0;
    if  (amountYears == 1) {
        yearIndex == 0;
    }
    else {
        if (year == "2010") {
            yearIndex = 0;
        }
        else if (year == "2011") {
            yearIndex = 1;
        }
        else if (year == "2012") {
            yearIndex = 2;
        }
        else if (year == "2013") {
            yearIndex = 3;
        }
        else if (year == "2014") {
            yearIndex = 4;
        }
        else if (year == "2015") {
            yearIndex = 5;
        }
    }

    if (field == "team_name") {
        if (order == "decr") {


            cout << "\n\nDecreasing Order" << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < NO_TEAMS; i++) {
                cout << ptr[yearIndex].teams[i].team_name;
            }
        }
        else if (order == "incr") {

            cout << "\n\nIncreasing Order" << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < NO_TEAMS; i++) {
                cout << ptr[yearIndex].teams[NO_TEAMS - 1 - i].team_name;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (field == "games") {
        if (order == "decr") {
             quicksortGames(ptr, 0, NO_TEAMS - 1, yearIndex, order);
            cout << "TEAM" << "\t\t" << "Number Of Games Decreasing";
            for (int i = 0; i < NO_TEAMS; i++) {
                cout << ptr[yearIndex].teams[i].team_name << " " << ptr[yearIndex].teams[NO_TEAMS - 1 - i].games;
            }
        }
        else if (order == "incr") {
            quicksortGames(ptr, 0, NO_TEAMS - 1, yearIndex, order);  
            cout << "TEAM" << "\t\t" << "Number Of Games Increasing";
            for (int i = 0; i < NO_TEAMS; i++) {
                cout << ptr[yearIndex].teams[NO_TEAMS - 1 - i].team_name << " " << ptr[yearIndex].teams[i].games;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in this function, I am sorting the code based on the field it is in and in incrementing/decrementing order.

```
void quicksortGames(annual_stats* pointer, int firstIndex, int lastIndex, int yearIndex, string order)
{
    //declaring index variables
    int pivotIndex, temp, index1, index2;

    if(firstIndex < lastIndex)
    {
        //assigning first element index as pivot element
        pivotIndex = pointer[yearIndex].teams[firstIndex].games;
        index1 = pointer[yearIndex].teams[firstIndex].games;
        index2 = pointer[yearIndex].teams[lastIndex].games;

        //Sorting in Ascending order with quick sort
        while(index1 < index2)
        {
            while(pointer[yearIndex].teams[index1].games <= pointer[yearIndex].teams[pivotIndex].games && index1 < lastIndex)
            {
                index1++;
            }
            while(pointer[yearIndex].teams[index2].games <= pointer[yearIndex].teams[pivotIndex].games)
            {
                index2--;
            }

            if(index1<index2)
            {
                //Swapping opertation
                temp = pointer[yearIndex].teams[index1].games;
                pointer[yearIndex].teams[index1].games = pointer[yearIndex].teams[index2].games;
                pointer[yearIndex].teams[index2].games = temp;
            }
        }

        //At the end of first iteration, swap pivot element with index2 element
        temp =  pointer[yearIndex].teams[pivotIndex].games;
        pointer[yearIndex].teams[pivotIndex].games =  pointer[yearIndex].teams[index2].games;
        pointer[yearIndex].teams[index2].games = temp;

        //Recursive call for quick sort, with partiontioning
        quicksortGames(pointer, firstIndex, index2-1, yearIndex, order);
        quicksortGames(pointer, index2+1, lastIndex, yearIndex, order);
    }
}
```

This function serves to quick sort the games. I made it separately because quick sort is recursive and thus I can't quick sort inside the previous function. I got the quick sort from this website: http://www.cprogramto.com/c-program-quick-sort/.

So basically, i'm trying to get all the inputs, stick them inside a function that sorts by field/order, and then specifically call the quick sort for the field.

The code compiles but I am currently receiving a segmentation fault 11 error whenever I attempt to run the code with something along the lines of qsort 2015 games decr, etc. When I omit the qsort, my code runs and works for the other sorting algorithms (not shown here) so I am sure the error is within quick sort. Will someone please help me see where exactly my error is?

Comment: If you run it in a debugger (like `gdb`) it will show you exactly which line of code caused the segfault.  You can even see the values of variables in the state that caused it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
    pivotIndex = pointer[yearIndex].teams[firstIndex].games;
    index1 = pointer[yearIndex].teams[firstIndex].games;
    index2 = pointer[yearIndex].teams[lastIndex].games;
    ...
    while(pointer[yearIndex].teams[index1].games <= pointer[yearIndex].teams[pivotIndex].games && index1 < lastIndex)
```

You set the *array index* (index1, index2) to the *number of games*.

That's not guaranteed to be less than the # of elements in the teams array.

So you wind up accessing the teams array out of bounds == segfault.

More Info: Compare your code to the site you got the algorithm from:

```
   ...
   index2 = lastIndex;

    //Sorting in Ascending order with quick sort
    while(index1 < index2)
    {
        while(array[index1] <= array[pivotIndex] && index1 < lastIndex)
        {
            index1++;
    ....
```

Index is the position in the array, where array[index] is the *value*.  In your case, you are doing the comparison in the (inner) while loop correctly:

```
    while(pointer[yearIndex].teams[index1].games <= pointer[yearIndex].teams[pivotIndex].games && index1 < lastIndex)
```

but you set the indexes incorrectly:

```
    index1 = pointer[yearIndex].teams[firstIndex].games;
```

To make it more concrete, suppose there were 10 teams, but the first team (team #0) played 1000 games.  Then your code does this:

```
    index1 = pointer[yearIndex].teams[0].games; // index1=1000

    while(pointer[yearIndex].teams[1000].games <= 
              pointer[yearIndex].teams[1000].games && 1000 < 9)
```

The problem is teams[1000] isn't valid if there are only 10 teams and when you access an array out of bounds like this in C, you get a segfault (if you're lucky) or corrupt memory and/or a security bug (if you're unlucky).

Also, the suggestion made in comments to learn a source debugger (GDB, or whatever - depending on your platform) is critical to learning C.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Sorry, I just need a bit of clarification because i'm having trouble comprehending (my fault) your comment. I'm setting the array index to the part where the games are displayed because I'm trying to sort between the scores of the games. In addition to that, the number of games is equivalent to the number of teams because each team plays 1 game. With those 2 statements being said, am I still accessing the teams array out of bonds?

Comment: @somanyerrorswhy Expanded answer to hopefully make clearer.
Also: the # of teams can't be equivalent to the # of games because 1 game requires at least 2 teams, right?